# Python unit testing for code containing with statement

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have the following function I'd like to write tests for.

```
def _find_latest_backup(self):
    """
    Find the latest backup in S3 bucket
    """
    aem_instance_type = self.instance_of
    if aem_instance_type == 'standby':
        aem_instance_type = 'author'

    with S3Bucket(name=self.s3_bucket) as bucket:
        objects = bucket.objects.filter(
            Prefix=self.s3_folder + "/aem_" + aem_instance_type,
        )
        print objects
        try:
            return max(objects, key=attrgetter('last_modified')).Object()
        except ValueError:
            self.logger.info("No backups found in %s/aem_%s", self.s3_folder, aem_instance_type)
```

My unittest looks like this,

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('s3_obj_summaries,latest_key', [
        (
            [
                MockS3ObjectSummary(
                    key='aem-cpp-dev-01/backup1',
                    last_modified=datetime(2017, 1, 10, 15, 0)
                ),
                MockS3ObjectSummary(
                    key='aem-cpp-dev-01/backup2',
                    last_modified=datetime(2017, 2, 11, 15, 0)
                ),
                MockS3ObjectSummary(
                    key='aem-cpp-dev-01/backup3',
                    last_modified=datetime(2017, 3, 12, 15, 0)
                ),
                MockS3ObjectSummary(
                    key='aem-cpp-dev-01/backup4',
                    last_modified=datetime(2017, 4, 12, 15, 0)
                ),
            ],
            "aem-cpp-dev-01/backup4"
        ),
    ])
    def test_find_latest_backup(self, mocker, s3_obj_summaries, latest_key):
        """ Test getting the latest backup file """
        bucket = mocker.patch('aem_management.restore.S3Bucket')
        bucket.__enter__.objects.filter.return_value = True
        restore_manager = blank_restore_manager()
        assert restore_manager._find_latest_backup().key == latest_key
```

However I don't get the correct value for return_value. Output I'm seeing is

```
 with mocker.patch('aem_management.restore.S3Bucket', return_value=mock_bucket) as bucket:
            restore_manager = blank_restore_manager()
>           assert restore_manager._find_latest_backup().key == latest_key
E           AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'
```

This is the first time I'm writing tests for code containing with statement and do I need do so anything different to make this work?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Mock boto3.resource instead will test on the resource bucket attributes and functions.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('s3_obj_summaries,latest_key', [
    (
        [
            MockS3ObjectSummary(
                key='aem-cpp-dev-01/backup1',
                last_modified=datetime(2017, 1, 10, 15, 0)
            ),
            ...
        ],
        "aem-cpp-dev-01/backup4"
    ),
])
@mock.patch("boto3.resource")
def test_find_latest_backup(self, s3_obj_summaries, latest_key, mock_boto):
    """ Test getting the latest backup file """
    mock_bucket = mock.Mock()
    mock_bucket.objects.filter.return_value = s3_obj_summaries
    mock_boto.return_value.Bucket = mock_bucket
    restore_manager = blank_restore_manager()
    assert restore_manager._find_latest_backup().key == latest_key
```